# Multiple Column Lookup field from Access to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, query, microsoft-access

I have two fields called "Tool ID" and "Tool Name" in my main "Tools" table in Access.

"Tool ID" is set as the primary key, in that it gives each tool a unique autogenerated number.

When I create a multiple column lookup field in my "Interfaces" table, I create "Tool ID" again.

"Tool ID" this time has two columns in the field such as "Tool ID" and "Tool Name" and it is returning the number value of "Tool ID".

When I move the "Interfaces" table to Sharepoint as a Sharepoint list that is linked to the "Interfaces" table within Access, the values that "Tool ID" shows is the "Tool ID" number values.

There is no "Tool Name" to the right of "Tool ID" in the "Tool ID" lookup field.  In Sharepoint, the field type of "Tool ID" for the "Interfaces" table is set to "Lookup" but it only shows one column not two columns in the field.

If I happen to create a lookup field in Sharepoint called "Tool ID", I have it set to grab and show the "Tool ID" data from "Tools" table as the value for "Tool ID".

Sharepoint also prompts me to add additional columns which I add "Tool Name" from "Tools" table as a additional column for the lookup field.  When I create the lookup field, Sharepoint decides to add "Tool Name" as an extra column in the "Interfaces" list and names it as "Tools: Tool Name."

The question that I have is :
**"Is there a way that you can create the Sharepoint lookup column of "Tool ID" to be the exact same way as Access's "Tool ID" multiple column lookup?"**

If there is anybody out there that has a solution to this problem, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post the same question on more than one StackExchange site.